# Convert XML to JSON with different property names using Jackson

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I have the next task: read XML file from some directory and convert it to JSON string.
The problem: initial XML and JSON have different names for corresponding properties, e.g. `x_date` in XML and `j_date` in JSON.

I have created the class with required field for JSON with such annotations:

```
public class Card {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "x_date")
  @JsonProperty("j_date")
  private String date;
  // other fields
```

I have tried to serialize/deserialize test XML file, and it's seems work correctly.
But I'm not sure that is ok to annotate fields with `@JacksonXmlProperty` and `@JsonProperty` annotations at the same time. Maybe it's better to create one class per XML part and one for the JSON and transfer the data between them some mapper (e.g. Orika)?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Underscore-java library has methods U.fromXmlMap(xml) and U.toJson(map). You may read data modify it and generate json.

Comment: @Valentyn Kolesnikov, sorry but the question is about Jackson and better aproach

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this by splitting logic in two separate classes: `Card.class` for XML data with help of `@JacksonXmlProperty` annotation and `CardDto.class` which uses `@JsonProperty`. Mapping between these classes is handled by Orika mapper.

This split will ease further customization of both classes and will allow add new functionality (e.g. persist data to the database using new entity class).